# Congruences: Exponent cancelation law?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Is this valid?

> If $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod n \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod n $

Comment: No. Take for example $n = 4$, $a = 1$ and $b = 3$.

Comment: @Shobhit What has that got to do with anything?

Comment: It's true, if $n$ is a prime.

Comment: I can't resist pointing out that if it's not valid, then it's not a theorem. Unless mathematics is inconsistent, of course …

Comment: What about: $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod m \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod m $ ?

Answer (score 4):

No,

> $$a^n \equiv b^n \pmod n \Rightarrow a \equiv b  \pmod n$$ is not valid.

As Tobias writes in the comments, take the counterexample $$n = 4, a = 1, b = 3$$

$$1^4 \equiv 3^4 \pmod 4 \iff 1\equiv 81\pmod 4 \not\Rightarrow 1\equiv 3 \pmod 4$$

If you add the additional restriction on $n$ that $n$ be *prime*, then the implication is true.

Comment: Nice write - up +1